# How to set up environment variable for PHP to access in centos?

Tags: php, apache, centos, environment

I need to set an **environment variable** in a way that a PHP script is able to access it

my system is **Centos 6, 64 bits** , with Apache server and PHP

Basically I'm using a third party linux library that uses xulrunner. Xulrunner is installed on a folder in the centos server.

I need to set an environment variable to indicate this tool where xulrunner is installed.

When i set that environment variable using

```
 Export Variable=location
```

In the `ssh` command line, it works great, perfect, and the tool executes perfect

but when I try from php it fails because its not finding the location, because obviously its not accessing that environment variable

so I need help to set an environment variable in a way that PHP script and user apache can access it

thank you

Comment: Did you try to use `getenv()`? Check it http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php, and show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the environment variable is not defined when you executes the script, try this:

1.- Edit your .bash_profile and add this line (put `xulrunner` directory if you want):

```
export PATH_XUL=/tmp
```

2.- Reload console
3.- Executes this php (it should write `/tmp`)

```
<?
  echo getenv("PATH_XUL");
?>
```

This environment variable is declared for your user, to declare variable to all users you can add the `export` directive to `/etc/profile.d/xul.sh`

If i don't understand your problem correctly, let me know

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `mod_env` enabled for Apache. Then, in your Apache configuration file, you can add this line at an appropriate location:

```
SetEnv VARIABLE=Location
```

You can then access it via `$_SERVER['VARIABLE']`.